# How to disable a Dynamic button by clicking another Dynamic button in android

Tags: android

I am creating 4 buttons dynamically in android in loop. The number of buttons can be increased from four in other cases. Now I am trying to disable all other buttons while clicking one button. I am trying to do this by array of button object.

```
Button btn[] = new Button[4];

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
  TableLayout layout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableForEvents);
  btn[i]=new Button(this);
  btn[i].setID(i);
  btn[i].setText("Button"+i);
  layout.addView(btn[i]);
  btn[i].setText(i);  
 }
```

This code is giving me a null pointer exception and results in application crash. So I am unable to perform next operation of enabling or disabling. Kindly tell me the solution or if there is another way to solve this problem

Comment: at which line you are getting NullPointerException?

Comment: could you please post your logcat?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that R.id.tableForEvents is present in the current layout for the activity.
you should be getting layout as null

also move the below code outside the for loop (no need to instantiate multiple times.)

```
TableLayout layout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableForEvents);
```